# What is subprocess.Popen doing that could result in "Software caused connection abort"?

Tags: python, subprocess, fuse

I have a Python program which runs successfully. If I change this line:

```
os.system("ls /path")
```

to this:

```
subprocess.Popen(["ls /path"], shell=True)
```

Then the `ls` command generates the following error:

```
ls: cannot access '/path': Software caused connection abort
```

What is different about these two methods of running `ls`?

N.B. `/path` is the mount point for a FUSE filesystem which I am testing. I am certain that is relevant as I observe no difference between the two cases above when the `ls` command is pointed to a non-FUSE path. But what is Python doing differently to get `ls` to trigger the different behaviour?

This is Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: ``Software caused connection abort`` sounds like something goes wrong with FUSE's socket. Is your filesystem still mounted and operational after this error?

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, both methods should be basically the same. You can try to run `strace` on both versions and check what is the difference in your particular case:

```
strace -f ./system.py >/dev/null 2> system.strace
strace -f ./popen.py >/dev/null 2> popen.strace
```

where `system.py` would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["ls /path"], shell=True)
```

and `popen.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
os.system("ls /path")
```

Moreover you can consider logging incoming requests in `getattr()` call of your fuse filesystem.

Another interesting hint is the error message, which looks like a socket related error.